# How to adjust 100% on my table height in all Screen resolution

Tags: asp.net

I have a table and the border width is 1.

How can I adjust the height to 100 % in all screen resolutions?
Or using jQuery how can I dynamically change the table heights?

I am new in web application

please help?...

rajesh

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0    Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>

<script src="./Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('#SprImg').attr("height", jQuery(window).height());
}); 
</script>

<body>

<table id="Table1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" runat ="server" width="100%" border="0" align="left">
    <tr>
            <td id="LeftPane"    align="left" valign="top" width="175" runat="server"  ></td>
            <td id="RightPane"  align="left" width="*.*" runat="server" valign="top">
             <img id="SprImg" src="./Image/login.gif"  alt="" /> 

            </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you show the code you're using and describe (perhaps even with a mocked up screen shot) what you're trying to achieve?  It's not clear from the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a trick to make that. Place an `img` somewhere in your `table` that takes a full column from top to bottom, that is non-visible. Then onload you change this image height to the document height, and you force the table to take this height.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#SprImg').attr("height", jQuery(window).height());
});
```

and the image, that is **1x1 pixel transparent gif**.

```
 <img id="SprImg" src="/images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="1" alt="" />
```

Place it somewhere inside a column that is from up to down. Now you can bind the window change size, to constantly change the image height to the window height in case that the user resize the browser.

The full page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery('#SprImg').attr("height", jQuery(window).height());
    }); 
    </script>

</head>
<body>

<table id="Table1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" runat ="server" width="100%" border="1" align="left">
    <tr>            
        <td id="LeftPane"    align="left" valign="top" width="175" runat="server">
            test text
        </td>
        <td id="RightPane"  align="left" width="*.*" runat="server" valign="top">
            <img id="SprImg" src="/img/ui/spacer.gif" width="1" height="1"  alt="" /> 
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @RajeshAbraham You are welcome, and welcome to stackoverflow. Here you do not need to ask for help, or ask "any ideas" nether to say many thanks. The thanks is to vote and accept the correct answer. People here they help if they know, and if you make a good question. :)

Comment: hi Aristos. it is not increasing the image. i posted the code. could you check it?.

Comment: @RajeshAbraham give some moment to debug it. I debug it and its working ! check if your program not found the image, or the jquery. I just copy/paste the code that is working to me.

Comment: displaying  actual image , image not increasing.

Comment: @RajeshAbraham check if you really load the jQuery. Open the javascript error panel. I just check it and working ! See the code I type, is copy/paste and its working.