# One of my html tables does not maintain height of 100 percent

Tags: asp.net, html, css, html-table

The dropdownlist populates the table's rows depending on the selection.  The table size is supposed to be fixed to full height, 100%, regardless of how many rows it has; however, its only ever as big as the number of rows in the table.

Here is the markup I am using:

```
<table style="width:100%;height:100%">
    <tr>
        <td class="auto-style9">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTechnicians" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"
            OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlTechnicians_SelectedIndexChanged">
                <asp:ListItem Selected="True">Online</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Offline</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>All Users</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
         <td>
             <asp:Table ID="tblTechnicians" CssClass="tblTechnicians"
             runat="server">
             </asp:Table>
         </td>
         </tr>
</table>
```

And the CSS for class tblTechnicians:

```
.tblTechnicians 
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;            
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: There is no need to define height as 100%. it will automatically increased as row being inserted.

Comment: i don't want it automatically adjusted.  i want it at a fixed  height of 100%, thanks though

Comment: I think that this answer can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8977470/how-to-adjust-100-on-my-table-height-in-all-screen-resolution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TABLE structures/elements are not DIVs. You cannot force a table to assume an arbitrary height in every scenario. Perhaps you should use DIVs instead to accomplish your layout objectives?? I've also tried all of the above to no avail. Unless I'm missing something.

You can however set your table height to match 100% (or whatever %) of your window height with JQuery:

```
$("table").css('height', $(window).height());
```

Good Luck

Answer (score 2):

You need to set a height of 100% on the parent containers. Including HTML and Body, such as:

```
html,body,form {height:100%}
```

If there are any other containers this table sits in they also need height of 100% setting.

Comment: already had all that set to 100% previously.  I'll double check but i'm pretty sure every container is 100%.

Comment: Don't forget your form too - I had this issue a few days ago, had me stumped only to notice the asp.net form needed it setting too

Comment: I also read some time ago that the default doc type on .net doesn't take any notice of the table height. You could try doc type <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"> - might help?

Answer (score 2):

Try setting a min-height on it, ditto for any containers:

```
.tblTechnicians 
{
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;            
}
```

Comment: unfortunately min-height doesn't do anything

Comment: Try using a containing TD cell for all the rows and apply it to that?